# Dividing a "parent" spreadsheet into "child" spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help:

I have a macro that divides a "parent" spreadsheet into 36 "daughters" spreadsheets. According to a pre-established criterion.

In this "parent" spreadsheet there is a macro, which consists of adding customers, and when I divide the "parent" spreadsheet, the macro is linked to the original spreadsheet. How do I make this macro linked in the "daughter" spreadsheet?

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename: = _
     "----" _
     , FileFormat: = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup: = False
 ActiveWindow.Close
```

Comment: You'll need to modify the original adding customer macro for doing this.

Comment: You would need to show us the macro code for us to tell you how to change it.

Comment: But it is possible to copy the macro without having to do it manually?